# how to use sz,rz to transform files in tmux?

Tags: linux, tmux

I use xshell to ssh to a linux remote server without root
When I use tmux,sz and rz can't transform files anymore
Is there any way to use sz,rz in tmux?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This would be better asked on [superuser](http://superuser.com), which is for general computing questions.  You will also need to provide details about how exactly you're using rz/sz, where you're running `tmux` (on the local system or the remote system) and what errors (if any) you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will edit my questions and reasked on superuser.